# For loop not applying style to first value

Tags: php

```
<?php
$i=5;
while ($i<=15){
 echo "<style> h3 {color:red;}</style>", $i, "<h3>","<br>";
i++
}
```

Please correct
[Style not applied to First element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/of0Pq.png)

Comment: `echo "<h3 style='color:red;'>", $i, "</h3>","<br>"`

Comment: It may also be worth looking at how a `for` loop can bring together the initialisation, condition and increment into 1 statement.

Comment: Please share more details about your problem. The code that you've provided does not contain a `for` loop. Also, the generated markup is invalid

Comment: The loop concept is clear. However, I was checking the styling of elements using <style> tag. I was not clear as to how the first element is not getting the style but the rest of the elements in the list. <style> was point to I wanted to highlight.

Comment: The given code is not able to generate valid markup - you should start fixing that first, and then check whether it's working

Comment: Yes, the markup is the concern. Was trying to implement the standard <style> h3 {color:red}</style>, format.

Comment: Thanx all for the insights

Answer (score 2):

Using the `<style>` tag is a good idea, but you only need it once. I placed it before the loop, so it would affect the HTML tags that follow. The `<h3>` tag always needs an ending `</h3>` tag.

```
<?php

echo "<style>\nh3 {color:red;}\n</style>\n";
$i=5;
while ($i <= 15) {
    echo "<h3>$i</h3><br>\n";
    i++;
}
```

I added some `\n` returns so the HTML source code would look better.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   $i = 5;
    while ($i <= 15){
        echo '<h3 style="color:red;">' . $i . '</h3>';
        $i++;
    }
```

Comment: Yes, thanx.this is the 2nd thing I wanted to achieve.

Comment: Tried the standard format, it works - 
<?php
$i=5;
while ($i<=15){
 echo "<style> h3 {color:red;} </style>". $i . "<br>";
$i++;
}